# Image locked left attempted all html queries

Tags: html, alignment

I queried in google how to center an image designed as a logo. Put it in a `<div>` tag `<span>` `<p>`.
entered in CSS class-rules display: block; margin: 0 auto; etc. Entered accompanying text in index.html. It still displays in the left top of browser window. What next to try?

Comment: Please include the [relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. It's better to put your current code. But if I get the target true, these examples can be helpful.

**Nutshell**: use `width: 100%;` for the container and `text-align: center;` for the child holder (here `span` element)

Hope this helps.

```css
/* example 1 */
.text-center{
    text-align: center;
}


/* example 2*/
.main-div{
    width: 100%;
    
}

.main-div span{
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h2> Example 1</h2>
<div class="text-center">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">
</div>

<h2> Example 2 </h2>
<div class="main-div">
  <span>
    <p>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">
    </p>
  </span>
</div>
```